# How to overload the constructor (not the initializer) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a class named `Foo`, then normally a call using syntax `Foo()` constructs a new instance and initializes it using the `__init__` (method/function).   I would like a slightly different (optimized) behavior.  I would like to memoize the instances according to the arguments of `Foo(...)` and if ever the same arguments are given, then return the same/identical instance as before, otherwise continue with the default construction protocol.  I'll need of course to *somewhere* implement a cache to memoize the object.  I could put that cache in a global variable or even in a property on the class itself.

But does the Python object system allow me to do this?

As I understand `__init__` CANNOT be used for this purpose as its return value is ignored by the system.

Of course, one way of course is to never call `Foo()` directly in my code, but always call `makeFoo`, but please note that that is not my question.   This would be pretty awkward because my program has a hierarchy of such classes, only some of which are memorable.   I don't want to make this *different* visible to the application programmer.

Comment: Well, most importantly, check out `__new__` and `lru_cache`.

Comment: Thanks for the hints.  BTW I did indeed spend *a fraction of the time* as you suggested investigating.   But I kept falling on information about `__init__` and people calling it a constructor, when it is it no really a constructor, but an initializer.